# Somehow I lost my configs/userdata after domainchange

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008

While working on Windows Server 2008 I changed the domain and I also created a new domain with dcpromo. I shut the system down and when I brought it back up, I had to log in with the new domain's credentials. For example `newdomain\newuser`.

After I logged in I saw that I lost all of my configurations. I thought I could recover the configurations by logging in with the old domain credentials. For exampls: `olddomain\olduser`. However, I logged in with the old credentials and I still dont see the configurations that existed in the old domain. How can I regain access to the old domain's information and configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid there isn't a lot you CAN do. Some background:

Users on Windows in a domain have both a name and the Security Identifier (SID). For domains, part of the SID contains the SID of the domain itself.

For machines in the domain, they resolve each user based on the SID since the SID of each user is unique.

When setting up a profile, a machine in the domain will assign a wide variety of rights to that user to the profile directory itself.

When you change the domain, but keep the same user-name, as far as the machine in the domain is concerned it is a completely separate user (different SIDs). So it creates a brand new profile.

As of Windows Vista (Server 2008) Microsoft removed the ability to copy profiles between users. They did this because there were problems, sometimes significant problems, with the copied profile.

I'm afraid there is nothing to be done here but re-do all of your settings.